# Blender 2.91.0: How to re-align the local axis of an object that has 0 rotations to the global axis?

Tags: axis

An object that has 0 rotations displays the local axis that's not aligned to the global axis.

Please see the following picture.

[image: Weird local axis rotation]

All parent objects have 0 rotations.

How can I re-align the local axis to the global axis?

The object itself has a few child objects, and that child objects' local axis and rotations must not be changed.

Blender version is 2.19.0.

**UPDATE 1:**

The object and it's parents' delta transform rotations are all 0 too.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I've included the blender file that has the problem - using Blend-Exchange (Please see 'Front Arm' object):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out where did the rotation come from.

Only Clear parent of object, Apply rotation then Set parent back lead to the desired result.

https://youtu.be/jkcoP4RKSnw

an interesting question - how did it happen? I hope the topic will continue

Comment: Thank you! It works. BTW, I tried to see the properties of the object with python script. With the object selected, I printed `bpy.context.object.matrix_local`. The 'shape' of the matrix values were somewhat different from the other object - maybe the rotation was included.

Answer (score 0):

Besides primary transformations blender has [Delta Transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/transforms.html) which useful in some cases.

It's located in Properties > Object > Transform > Delta Transform:

[image: Delta Transform]

You can transfer primary transformations to deltas by applying them:

[image: apply Delta]

Blender hasn't Apply Delta Transform operator. You can only copy Delta transform to primary manually, reset deltas to default then Apply main transform to data.

Comment: Thank you. But the object's delta transform rotations are all 0 too. I've updated my question.

Comment: May be it transformed with armature poses?

Comment: I didn't do any rigging. (BTW, I use Blender for hobby. So, my knowledge for Blender is limited.) But I used many custom transform orientations - with edge or face.

Comment: Can you share your blend file or copy & paste only problem object to new file and share it? my guesses are over

Comment: I've shared the blender file using Blend-Exchange. Please see UPDATE 2. Thank you.